# Populating a list view, from view model class in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, binding, viewmodel

I am trying to add a list of model objects to my list view
This is my View Code which contains a list view as a Grid View

```
<ListView Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Name="EmployeeDetailsListView">
    <ListView.View>

        <GridView>

            <GridViewColumn  Header="{x:Static resx:Resources.String1}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmployeeID}"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn  Header="{x:Static resx:Resources.String2}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn  Header="{x:Static resx:Resources.String3}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn  Header="{x:Static resx:Resources.String10}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Gender}"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn  Header="{x:Static resx:Resources.String11}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Phone}"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn  Header="{x:Static resx:Resources.String7}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Phone}" ></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn  Header="{x:Static resx:Resources.String8}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Phone}" ></GridViewColumn>

        </GridView>                           
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

My View Model Contains the following code

```
List<EmployeeModel> eList = new List<EmployeeModel>();
eList.Add(EmployeeModel);
EmployeeDetailsListView.ItemsSource = eList;
```

I am trying to populate the List View from the View Model, but the ListView is not getting recognised in the ViewModel Class

I am getting the following error

"The name 'EmployeeDetailsListView' does not exist in the current context "
I want to know how to access ListView present in View.xaml from my ViewModel, so that I can populate the list view.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Your view model must not know the view. Instead, it should have a public property of type `ObservableCollection<EmployeeModel>`, e.g. named EmplyeeList. You would then bind the ListView's `ItemsSource` in XAML like `ItemsSource="{Binding EmplyeeList}"`. Because it's an ObservableCollection, the UI would now automatically be updated when the collection changes.

Comment: Hi Clemens, I tried adding the following in my view model but it still doesnt work      -                                                                                                                                                                                                              public ObservableCollection<EmployeeModel> EmployeeList
        {
            get
            {
                ObservableCollection<EmployeeModel> eList = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeModel>();
                eList.Add(EmployeeModel);
                return eList;
            }
        }

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Clemens It worked after making some changes in my View Model